# Error when updating

Tags: 12.04, ppa

Every time I run `apt-get update` I get the error for one PPA:

> W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/gb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

I have 38 packages under "not being installed" but they are mostly to do with graphics and would like to install them.

Is there a way to sort this?